# British Summer Time with jQuery Datepicker (calculation lost 1 day)

Tags: javascript, datetime, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use [Vue.js with jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and see the issue with calculation of how many days are left to the selected date:
[image]

Calculation the difference in days:

```
getDifferenceInDays: function(date1, date2) {
  const diffTime = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); //Math.abs(...);
  const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return diffDays;
},
```

As a result I don't see 13 days left. Perhaps the issue related to the British Summer Time which ends on 27th October:
[image: British Summer Time ends on 27th October]

Could you suggest any idea how to fix this issue.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, this is caused by a Daylight Saving Time (DST) transition, specifically the end of DST in the UK on the 27th of October.

Dates, Times and Timezones are *really* tricky in JavaScript. The native Date object is very awkward to deal with when we're accessing different timezones.

I would suggest checking out a library that is better at this kind of thing:  [moment](https://momentjs.com/) and [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) are very good at handling DST changes correctly.

The reason you're getting the incorrect result is that you're looking at the difference between dates in the UTC timezone (since getTime() always returns the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC (the Unix Epoch)).

The result (in your case) will be 13.04 (or 13 + 1/24) days since the UTC offset changes between the two dates (from UTC+01 to UTC+00).

For example, 12:00 on the 14th of October London Time is 11:00 UTC,
while 12:00 on the 27th of October London Time is 12:00 UTC. So the difference will be 313 hours, or 13.04 days.

Since you're calling Math.ceil, this will round up to 14, which is not correct.

This works when both dates are within the same UTC offset (e.g. both in summer, both in winter). But then they are either side of a DST change, you will get an incorrect result.

The code below will calculate the days between two dates *in the specified timezone*. You can pass a third argument of *true* to moment.diff to get the fractional days. (This will be 0 in this case).

If you don't wish to use another library such as moment, you can simply use Math.round to get the approximate difference in days. This *will not* be as robust, since if date2 is less than 12 hours ahead of date1 you'll get zero days difference. 
As long as you're aware of this, it may suffice for your needs. I've added a getDifferenceInDaysRounding to show this.

```js
const CURRENT_TIMEZONE = "Europe/London";

// Date 1 is 12:00, 14th October, London time
const date1 = moment.tz("2019-10-14T12:00:00", CURRENT_TIMEZONE).toDate();

// Date 2 is 12:00, 27th October, London time
const date2 = moment.tz("2019-10-27T12:00:00", CURRENT_TIMEZONE).toDate();

function getDifferenceInDaysOriginal (date1, date2) {
  const diffTime = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
  let diff1 = diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return diffDays;
}

// Use with caution.. this will not work in all cases!
function getDifferenceInDaysRounding (date1, date2) {
  const diffTime = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
  const diffDays = Math.round(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return diffDays;
}

function getDifferenceInDaysTimezoneAware(date1, date2, timezone) {
  // Ensure the dates are in the correct timezone.
  const dateLocal1 = moment.tz(date1.getTime(), timezone);
  const dateLocal2 = moment.tz(date2.getTime(), timezone);

  // Pass false to return the integer number of days. NB, this will be 0 for less than 24 hours difference. Pass true to get the fractional days.
  return dateLocal2.diff(dateLocal1, "days", false);
}

console.log("Original result:", getDifferenceInDaysOriginal(date1, date2));
console.log("Get difference (rounding):", getDifferenceInDaysRounding(date1, date2));
console.log("Timezone-aware result:", getDifferenceInDaysTimezoneAware(date1, date2, CURRENT_TIMEZONE));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-1970-2030.js"></script>
```